# How to write results from php to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I need to write the following to a database: first integer, second integer and the result. On the end of page I wrote some code to try to put the results to a database, but it only writes first integer and second integer but not the actual result.

I am beginner at this.

First part of code as you can see, is the actual calculation of greatest common divisor. Second part which I wrote is supposed to write results to my database, but it only writes 1 and 2 integer not the actual results.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
#Created Dec 18 02:09:31 2016
#author: Justin, owner of linuxwebdevelopment.com
$first_integer = $_POST['integer1'];
$second_integer = $_POST['integer2'];
**$result = $_POST ['result'];**   //These I wrote myself i think it is wrong

function gcd($x, $y)
{
    /*This function finds the gcd (greatest common divisor)
    of the two integers $x and $y and returns the gcd
    It uses the Euclidean Algorithm.
    The general form for the Euclidean Algorithm is
    r_k = q_(k+2)*r_(k+1) + r_(k+2)
    Here _ denotes subscripts. 
    Above Parentheses indicate that the subscript is more than 1 character long
    for the code I just remove the _ and ()
    initially $r_k = $x and $r_(k+1) = $y
    */
    if ($x == $y) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($x == 0 or $y == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        #we assume $x is greater than y. If $y is greater than $x, 
        #just switch them
        if ($y > $x) {
            $temp = $x;
            $x = $y;
            $y = $temp;
        }
        $rk = $x;
        $rkp1 = $y;
        $rkp2 = $rk % $rkp1;
        if ($rkp2 == 0)
            return $rkp1;
        else {
            while ($rkp2 != 0) {
                $rk = $rkp1;
                $rkp1 = $rkp2;
                $rkp2 = $rk % $rkp1;
            }
            return $rkp1;
        }
    }
}

$result = gcd($first_integer, $second_integer);
echo "Najväčší spoločný deliteľ $first_integer a $second_integer je $result";

**$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root")
or die("Nelze se připojit: " . mysql_error());
print "Připojeno úspěšně";
mysql_select_db("delitel") or die("Nelze vybrat databázi");
$a = $_POST["integer1"];
$b = $_POST["integer2"];
$c = $_POST["result"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO delitel(integer1,integer2,vysledok) values ('$a','$b','$c')");
mysql_close($link);
include("vypis.php");**
?>
```

And these I wrote myself but it only writes to a database first and second integer not the result. I need to write to a database: Result first integer and second integer. I wrote the two integers succesfully to my database, but the result doesn't end up there.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 3 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This basicly means that it would take less than a minute for any visitor of your website to do whatever they want with your database. That includes destroying it. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: it is just for a school project that i need to finish it is not actual website with some sensitive data ...

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you're still learning, learn it the right way from the start. Don't use weak excuses because you don't want to learn. In PHP 7, you simply _can't_ even use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They've been removed.

Comment: please help me with this if u can

Comment: `$c = $a + $b;`

Comment: i am sorry but i dont get it ?  
$c = $a + $b;

it supouse to be like this ? $c=$a + $b;["result"]; 

i am really not good at this

Comment: You wanted help on how to fix it. That's how you fix it. Just replace `$c=$_POST["result"];` with that in your code.

Comment: :D yeah but that wont write the greatest common divisor :D

Comment: Seriously, that entire code is just plain wrong to begin with. You wanted a quick fix, that's what I gave you. You want something better, rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Or if you want the result from your function, replace `$c` in your query with `$result`.

Comment: yeah well thank you for your quick fix unfortunately it does not solve my problem :/

Comment: It's because you don't seem to _understand_ anything from the code that's been given to you. Which I can understand since it's written quite unclear. Your question should've been: "How do I insert the result from the `gcd();` function to a database?"

Comment: $result=$_POST["result"]; ? like this ?

Comment: No. Let me walk you though what's happening. First you're saving the POST request headers inside `$first_integer` and `$second_integer`. Next you have a function `gcd();`. On this line `$result = gcd($first_integer, $second_integer);` you are inserting the integers into the function and save the result in `$result`;. So all that's left to do is insert `$first_integer`, `$second_integer` and `$result` into your database: `INSERT INTO delitel(integer1,integer2,vysledok) values ('$first_integer','$second_integer','$result')`. You don't need anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I admire your patience with me.

Comment: Patience isn't the issue. It's you actually wanting to learn something. We're not being assholes to you by telling you that you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions. We're saying it so you can learn and improve. It may not matter much in this situation, but when it actually does matter, you're gonna make mistakes because you did it wrong in the first place. And yes, people can actually _sue_ you in court for not protecting their data to the best of your abilities when that happens.

Comment: I mean, instead of giving some excuse why it's fine to use, you could've said: I don't know how to do that. Can you help me with it? I would've been more than happy to teach you how to do it right. As most members here would. We all applaud those that really want to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['result']` is not showing up in the database because it is a null value.
No data is getting stored in your `$c = $_POST['result'];`
So instead of using `$_POST['result']` simply use `$c = $result` as you are storing the return of your gcd funtion in `$result`.